# Get all id from Javascript objects

Tags: javascript

I have following object structure, and

```
[
  { id: 183, firstName: 'first0', lastName: 'last0', std: 0 },
  { id: 184, firstName: 'first1', lastName: 'last1', std: 1 },
  { id: 185, firstName: 'first2', lastName: 'last2', std: 2 }
]
```

I want to iterate through the object and get [183,184,185].
Here is what I have tried

```
alreadyCachedData = [
  { id: 183, firstName: 'first0', lastName: 'last0', std: 0 },
  { id: 184, firstName: 'first1', lastName: 'last1', std: 1 },
  { id: 185, firstName: 'first2', lastName: 'last2', std: 2 }
]
for (var key in alreadyCachedData[0]) {
  if (alreadyCachedData[0].hasOwnProperty(key)  == "id") {
    var val = alreadyCachedData[0][key];
    console.log(val);
  }
}
```

But I don't get required result, any help?

Comment: `alreadyCachedData[0].hasOwnProperty(key)  == "id"` will never be true, `hasOwnProperty` returns a boolean. Neither `true` nor `false` is ever `== "id"`.

Comment: What is `alreadyCachedData`? What does `alreadyCachedData[0].hasOwnProperty(key)` return?

Answer (score 4):

it's easy with [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields)

```js
const out = alreadyCachedData.map(o => o.id)
```